# Premiere Pro shifting keyframes during an insert edit

Tags: premiere, editing, keyframes

During an insert edit all clips (video and audio) shift right except the keyframes (track volume) themselves on the audio tracks. Similar if I select all and move, keyframes are not included. How can I shift the audio track along with its keyframes during an insert?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When I do an insert edit (using the shortcut '.' key) in CC 2018, I do not see this problem.

Make sure the Source Patching on the audio tracks is selected correctly, otherwise the audio tracks won't move when you do the insert?  Apologies if this is teaching you to suck eggs - maybe a screen recording would better demo what's going wrong?

Before insert edit
[image]

After insert edit (note keyframes have moved)
[image]

Comment: I have selected Track keyframes/Volume and not Clip keyframes. I think this is my problem, as Track keyframes don't seem to shift when inserting. Think this is a hard stop problem and I need to redo my keyframes as clip keyframes? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you're right.